# WebAudioAPIでmp3をすべてダウンロードするのを待たずに再生を開始したい

Tags: javascript

## 質問

サイズの大きいmp3をXHRでロードし、WebAudioAPIを用いて再生しているのですが、ロードが完了するまでの待ち時間が発生します。
サイズが大きいmp3であっても待ち時間を少なく抑えて再生を開始する方法はありますでしょうか。

たとえば、SoundCloudは再生ボタンをクリックすると即座に再生が開始されます。デベロッパーツールで確認すると再生しながらロードを行っているのがわかります。
どのような実装でこれを実現しているのか分かっていないのですが、何かしらの方法があるのではないかと考えています。

## 待ち時間が発生してしまう実装

```js
(function () {
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var context = new AudioContext();

  loadSound('./audio/sample.mp3');

  function loadSound(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-');
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    request.onload = function() {
      context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        playSound(buffer);
      }, function () {
        console.debug('error');
      });
    };

    request.send();
  }

  function playSound(buffer) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media Source Extensionsという、JavaScriptでストリーミングするための標準APIがあります。
これを使ってみるのはいかがでしょうか?

参考
https://github.com/72lions/PlayingChunkedMP3MediaSourceAPI

[Media Source Extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/) W3Cでの仕様

#### 追記:

デベロッパーツールで音声ファイルのレスポンスのhttp statusを確認したところ、一般的な`200 OK`ではなく、`206 Partial Content`を返していました。

`206 Partial Content`はサーバーにデータ(今回の場合はmp3)の一部分を要求するものらしいです。
これを使っているのではないでしょうか?

参考
RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233
http://blog.cloudpack.jp/2014/08/12/mamma-mia-http-status-code-206-partial-content/

Comment: ありがとうございます！そういうものがあったんですね。見てみます！

Comment: あらためて、回答ありがとうございました。

紹介してもらったgithubの参考リポジトリの実装を見てみました。Demoを見てもたしかに短い待機時間で再生が開始されているのですが、mp3ファイルを細切れに分割してロードするということをしているため、この手法だとmp3ファイルを編集する手間が生じます。

この方法もひとつの解決法だとは思うのですが、できればmp3ファイルを編集することなく、ひとつのmp3ファイルで実現できないかと考えています（SoundCloudではそれが実現できているので何らかの方法があると考えています）。

もしご存知のかたがいましたらよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: @hogesuke httpの206を使っているのかもしれません。
回答にhttp 206について追記しました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます！range headerっていうのを使うんですね。試しにheaderを追加してxhrで取得してみると、一部分を取得できました。この方法で細切れで取得を繰り返せば、待機時間を少なくすることができそうです。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2):

`AudioBuffer`はせいぜい1分程度の比較的短めの音声のために設計されていて、たとえばCD一枚74分のデータ全体のような大きなデータを読み込むような目的には向いていません。

> このインターフェースはメモリ上に保持されるオーディオのリソース(ワンショットの音やその他の短いオーディオクリップ)を表します。 そのフォーマットは-1 ～ +1の名目上の範囲を持つ非インターリーブのIEEE 32ビット・リニアPCMです。 1つ以上のチャンネルを持つ事ができます。 典型的には、そのPCMデータは適度に(通常1分以内程度に)短いと見込まれます。 音楽の1曲分のような長時間の音に関してはaudio要素とMediaElementAudioSourceNodeによるストリーミングを使うべきです。

http://g200kg.github.io/web-audio-api-ja/#AudioBuffer

> これらのオブジェクトは短い、一般的には45秒未満の、断片的な音声を保持するために設計されています。それよりも長い音声は、MediaElementAudioSourceNodeのオブジェクトが適しています。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer

というわけで、`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`を使うのがいいと思います。`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`なら簡単にストリーミング再生で部分的に読み込みながら再生することが可能です。ただし、おそらくないと思いますが、万が一どうしてもXHRで読み込まなければならない理由があるのなら、`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`を使うことはできません。その場合は何らかの方法でオーディオファイルを分割して`AudioBuffer`に読み込むことになるでしょう。

## 追記: `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`で途中から再生するには

[`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)の[`currentTime`プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime)で現在の再生位置を設定できます。その後で`play`を呼び出せば途中から再生できます。たとえば、ローカルのオーディオファイルを開いて、ローパスフィルタをかけて途中から再生するコードは次のようになります。

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var audio = document.querySelector("audio");

var context = new AudioContext();
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

source.connect(filter);
filter.connect(context.destination);

input.addEventListener("change", function(){
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    audio.currentTime = 50; 
    audio.play();
});
```

```html
<input type="file"></input>
<audio controls />
```

Comment: すみません、確認するのが遅れてしまいました。xhrを使わずともストリーミングは可能なんですね。こちらも試してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、MediaElementAudioSourceNodeを試してみました。ロードしながらの再生ができることを確認できました。申し訳ないのですが、また質問をさせてください。100秒ある音声の50秒の位置から再生したいとした場合、先頭からロードするのではなく50秒の位置からロードを開始することは可能でしょうか？先頭からロードしてしまうと50秒の位置までロードされるのに時間がかかってしまうので、この待機時間を無くしたいと考えています。

Comment: 回答に追記しました。

Comment: 親切に本当にありがとうございます。サンプルコードまで書いてもらって助かります。
currentTimeの指定で途中から再生させることは実現できました。ただ、このときにロードは先頭から始まってしまい、やはり待機時間が発生してしまいます。別の質問としてこちらに投稿させていただきました。もし何か情報ありましたらまたよろしくお願いいたします。
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17744/